# How do I filter my array to iterate the $date one time for every $event on that date? php

Tags: php, html, loops

I am using the calendario calendar API. I've managed to get it working for one event per date, but I have multiple events on each date. Here is the format for multiple events on each date:

```
var events = {
    '09-08-2015' : [
        {content:'Event 1', url:'optional', note:'optional'},
        {content:'Event 2', catergory:'optional', and more..}
    ]
};
```

Here is my attempt at printing out my events on the calendar:

```
  <script>
    var canvasEvents = {
    <?php
        foreach($events as $event) {
            $d = date("m-d-Y", strtotime($event->event_date));
            $t = date("h:i A", strtotime($event->event_start_time));

        }

        for($i=0; $i<1; $i++){
            echo "'$d' : [{content:'<a href=\"event-single.php?id=$event->id\" target=_blank>$event->event_title</a>'},
                          {content:'<a href=\"event-single.php?id=$event->id\" target=_blank>$event->event_title</a>'},
            ]";
        }
    ?>
    };
    </script>
```

This results in just 2 events (duplicated) printed on one date on the calendar. I've limited $i to 1 as a test. I cannot cycle through the variables with $d[$i]. I tried printing out $d[0] which prints out the first item of the date as a string.

How can I print out all my events so that there are multiple event titles for each date?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an associative array like the JavaScript object you want. Then use `json_encode()` to convert that to a JavaScript object literal.

```
$canvas_events = [];
foreach ($events as $event) {
    $d = date("m-d-Y", strtotime($event->event_date));
    $canvas_events[$d][] = [
        'content' => "<a href=\"event-single.php?id=$event->id\" target=_blank>$event->event_title</a>", 
        'url' => $event->url,
        'note' => $event->note
    ];
}
?>
<script>
var canvasEvents = <?php echo json_encode($canvas_events); ?>;
</script>
```